# Advice to write/extend JQuery drag and drop where so DIVs can also be drop zones

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm a JQuery newbie and moderately competent JS programmer. I want to write a JQuery plug-in so I can drag and drop a DIV onto another DIV. If the other DIV is not a dropzone, then it simply calls a function of my choice. Perhaps dropping a draggable DIV onto another draggable DIV already exists which would be perfect, but I haven't found it.

If it doesn't exist, I wanted advice on the implementation.

Do I keep track of the x,y position and dimensions of every DIV so when a DIV is dropped onto another DIV (that may or may not be a dropzone) I can determine which DIV it was dropped upon?

Should I even do this using JQuery? Any other suggestions on my approach would also be appreciated!

Comment: You're looking for Droppable imho.. you can change accept property to a selector so that only certain things can be accepted as droppable - theres a bunch of events and stuff tha can help u customize it too
https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#accepted-elements

Answer (score 0):

This seemed interesting so I wrote a code, which covers the basics of what you want. Didn't want to make it over-complicated, so in this example, you can drag boxes inside the container area, and you can put box1 into box2.

This should cover up the overall idea, from here on you can write functions to detach boxes, apply extra styles etc. And better use event listeners though.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6LV25/

Here's the source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>BoxCeption</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function()
{

  //first let's make boxes movable, they can only be moved, when one of them, is clicked upon
  //in order to move it, we will dynamically change it's top,left values
  //based upon cursor x,y coordinates

  //define some variables
  var lastX;
  var lastY;
  var current_selected_box_left;
  var current_selected_box_top;
  var is_selected = false;
  var clicked_box_id;
  var boxOffsetx;
  var boxOffsety;
  var isoverbox2 = false;
  var container_width = 600;
  var container_height = 480;

  //set container size
  jQuery("#container").css({width : container_width, height : container_height});
  var parentOffset = jQuery("#container").offset(); 


  //when you have clicked on box
  jQuery(".draggableBox").on("mousedown",function()
  {
    is_selected = true;
    clicked_box_id = "#" + jQuery(this).attr("id");

  });

  jQuery(".draggableBox").on("mouseup",function()
  {
    is_selected = false;
    clicked_box_id = "";

    if(isoverbox2 == true)
    {
      jQuery("#box1").appendTo("#box2");
      jQuery("#box1").css({left : "20px", top : "20px"});
    }
  });


  //prevent boxes from going outside the container
  jQuery("#container").on("mousemove",function(event)
  {
    if(is_selected)
    {
      boxOffsetx = jQuery(clicked_box_id).width()/2;
      boxOffsety = jQuery(clicked_box_id).height()/2;

      //if still in container area
      if(parseInt(jQuery(clicked_box_id).css("left")) < container_width-boxOffsetx && parseInt(jQuery(clicked_box_id).css("top")) < container_height-boxOffsety && parseInt(jQuery(clicked_box_id).css("left")) > 0 && parseInt(jQuery(clicked_box_id).css("top")) > 0)
      {
        jQuery(clicked_box_id).css({left : event.pageX-parentOffset.left-boxOffsetx + "px",top : event.pageY-parentOffset.top-boxOffsety + "px"});
      }
      else if(parseInt(jQuery(clicked_box_id).css("left")) >= container_width-boxOffsetx)
      {
        jQuery(clicked_box_id).css({left : container_width-boxOffsetx-1 + "px",top : event.pageY-parentOffset.top-boxOffsety + "px"});
      }
      else if(parseInt(jQuery(clicked_box_id).css("left")) <= 0)
      {
        jQuery(clicked_box_id).css({left : 1 + "px",top : event.pageY-parentOffset.top-boxOffsety + "px"});
      }
      else if(parseInt(jQuery(clicked_box_id).css("top")) >= container_height-boxOffsety)
      {
        jQuery(clicked_box_id).css({left : event.pageX-parentOffset.left-boxOffsetx + "px",top : container_height-boxOffsety-1 + "px"});
      }
      else if(parseInt(jQuery(clicked_box_id).css("top")) <= 0)
      {
        jQuery(clicked_box_id).css({left : event.pageX-parentOffset.left-boxOffsetx + "px",top : 1 + "px"});
      }
    }

    //if box1 clicked and dragged into box2
    if(clicked_box_id == "#box1")
    {
      if(jQuery('#box2:hover').length > 0) 
      {
        jQuery("#box2").css("border","1px solid green");
        isoverbox2 = true;
      }
      else
      {
        jQuery("#box2").css("border","1px solid black");
        isoverbox2 = false;
      }
    }


  });

});

</script>

<style>

html
{
font-family: Times New Roman;
font-size: 12px;
color: black;
height: 100%;
}

body
{
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#container{border: 1px solid black; position: relative; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;margin-top: 100px;}
#box1{width: 100px;height: 100px; border: 1px solid blue; position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 200px;}
#box2{width: 150px;height: 150px; border: 1px solid black; position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 350px;}

</style>

</head>
<body>


<div id="container">

  Container

  <div id="box1" class="draggableBox">box1</div>
  <div id="box2" class="draggableBox">box2</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank-you, but this won't work. When you are dragging a DIV the only DIV that will return a non zero length will be the DIV you are dragging. Attempting to detect if you are hovering over another DIV while dragging a DIV won't work.

Comment: Revised: Thank-you, but this doesn't work. When you are dragging a DIV the only DIV that will return a non zero length of jQuery('#AnyDIV:hover').length  will be the DIV you are dragging. Attempting to detect if you are hovering over another DIV while dragging a DIV doesn't work, at least within the Chrome Browser.

Comment: Well, if that doesn't beat all: It does work in IE and Firefox, but not in Chrome!

Comment: Ah you are correct, doesn't work in Chrome. 
Well, the only other way, which I can think of, would be:
1. Calculate the dropzone - in previous example, it's the box2. Start with origin-point, which is top: 200px; left: 350px; , that's where the box2 is positioned, now add its width and height (150px;150px) and you have a dropzone.
2. You can call on mouseMove function, in which you check if your pointers current x,y is inside the dropzone. If yes, then you can merge those divs with append.